# MeshLab filters from Java application

Tags: java, 3d, meshlab

How can I call MeshLab filters from my java application?
I know that with MeshLabServer I can execute MeshLab commands, but I don't know how and if I can execute MeshLab commands only from MeshLabServer without installing MeshLab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to install almost the whole meshlab. All the filtering operations are implemented by means of plugins (as dynamically loaded library) so you need also all of them to use meshlabserver...